# Javascript for i not printing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've searched around and found no pure js solution to my issue that I can apply to my code.
It's a script that prints an array of images, but for now it only prints 1 array.
Pertinent code in html:

```
<div id="imgViewer"></div>
<script>
var imgViewerImages = ['img/imgViewer/1.png','img/imgViewer/2.png','img/imgViewer/3.png','img/imgViewer/4.png','img/imgViewer/5.png','img/imgViewer/6.png'];
</script>
<script src="services/imgViewer.js"></script>
```

And in JS:

```
function imgViewerPrinter(){
    var imgViewerTarget = document.getElementById('imgViewer');
    imgViewerImages.toString();

    for (var i=0;i<imgViewerImages.length;i++){
        imgViewerTarget.innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgViewerImages[i] + '">';
    }
}

window.onload = imgViewerPrinter();
```

I'm still a noob is JS so I ask for your pacience.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the array declaration and usage are in same file?

Comment: The array is in the HTML, then the JS script is called from a external file.

Comment: `imgViewerTarget.innerHTML = '<img` should be `imgViewerTarget.innerHTML += '<img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
imgViewerTarget.innerHTML += "<img src="' + imgViewerImages[i] + '">";
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks allot! Though I'll implement Luke14's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out an array of images shouldnt you have your HTML code in the loop making i the image number for example;

```
 for (var i=0;i<imgViewerImages.length;i++){
var imgViewerImages = ['img/imgViewer/' + [i] + '.png'];
  }
```

Comment: Almost... in this method, it literally prints [i].png. You need to use '.../'+i+'.png'

Comment: I can see how your code is more efficent. I can define a var with the location and the other with the array. But this is meant to be use by less tech-prone people, in which naming everything might be more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,Because your code  rewrite innerHTML again and again, so you get last iterated value.

Instead of manipulating DOM in every loop,Below code will manipulate your DOM one time only.

```
function imgViewerPrinter(){
    var imgViewerTarget = document.getElementById('imgViewer');

    var imgViewerImages_length = imgViewerImages.length;
    var image = '';
    for (var i=0;i<imgViewerImages_length;i++){
        image += '<img src="' + imgViewerImages[i] + '">';
    }
    imgViewerTarget.innerHTML = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this optimized soln.

```
 var imgViewerImages =['img/imgViewer/1.png','img/imgViewer/2.png','img/imgViewer/3.png','img/imgViewer/4.png','img/imgViewer/5.png','img/imgViewer/6.png'];

    function imgViewerPrinter(){

        var imgList=[];
        for (var i=0;i<imgViewerImages.length;i++){
            imgList.push('<img src="' + imgViewerImages[i] + '" />');
        }
         var imgViewerTarget = document.getElementById('imgViewer');
         imgViewerTarget.innerHTML = imgList.join('');
    }

    window.onload = imgViewerPrinter();
```

Comment: Avoid concatenation of string because it takes more memory.